# what's wrong with my code, I want to make the bird fly?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, game-development

I'm trying to make the bird fly when clicking space or click on-screen and if you left it, it will fall down (like Flappy Bird game)

but when I click space the bird goes up and never come down again

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WbF62.png)

```cs
public class Bird : MonoBehaviour
{
  private const float JUMP_AMOUNT = 100f;
    
  private Rigidbody2D birdRigidbody2D;
    
  private void Awake()
  {
    birdRigidbody2D = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
  }
    
  private void Update()
  {  
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) || Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    { 
      Jump();
    } 
  }

  private void Jump() 
  {
    birdRigidbody2D.velocity = Vector2.up * JUMP_AMOUNT;
  }
}
```

Comment: Where is the code to make the bird come down again?

Comment: Does the rigidbody have gravity enabled?

Answer (score 0):

It's because you set the velocity of your object everytime you hit the key. Velocity is the speed of your object. Unless there's some physical influence that speed will never change.

Therefore you should make sure that gravity is enabled on your rigidbody.

You should also use [AddForce](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.AddForce.html) instead of setting the velocity directly in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to activate gravity on your rigidbody:
[Rigidbody Gravity turned on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kywrG.jpg)

Make sure the box is checked
and use add force instead of velocity like:

```
birdRigidbody2D.AddForce(0, JUMP_AMOUNT * Time.deltaTime)
```